# Where can I download the .NET 4.5 Multitargeting Pack for my build server?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, .net-4.5

I want to build a .net 4.5/VS2012 solution in TeamCity. My builds work on the agent that has VS2012 installed, but on the agent that doesn't have VS2012, I get warnings like this:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(983,5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found.
>
> To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

Can I install the targets without installing all of Visual Studio 2012, like I could with .NET 4.0?

Where's the download?

(I feel ridiculous asking this...but I have searched and searched for it! Honest! [This site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/hh487283.aspx) suggests it's only available with VS2012, which seems like madness.)

Comment: Have you installed .NET 4.5 itself on the build agent? That may be enough.

Comment: Yes, I have--the 48mb download. It doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe this particular issue is actually only giving me build _warnings_, not errors. Not as big of a deal, but I'm still curious if there's a way...

Comment: I gave up and just installed [Visual Studio 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express) (for web). That fixed it.

Comment: Same here. Builds fine with build agent on development machine. Fails with same problem on the build server agent. Copying the folder and rebooting didn't help - guess it doesn't register it with the GAC correctly. Installing VS2012 for web now ... Damn you MS and your assembly fragmentation!

Answer (score 94):

You don't need to install any SDK. Just copy the following folder from your development machine into the same folder of your TFS build machine:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5

---

If this doesn't work for you, refer to: http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html where you'll find the SDKs you need. However note the comment from @Lu55: *Link to "Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8" from .NET Framework 4.5 section unexpectedly redirects to "Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1" which is for .NET Framework 4.5.1*.

---

@dotarj mentions: The link for Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8, which is actually for .NET Framework 4.5, is:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  Its easy, you likely have the files on your machine already, and it fixes the issue.

Comment: Be on the alert while using the page mentioned above! 
Link to "Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8" from .NET Framework 4.5 section unexpectedly redirects to "Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1" which is for .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: Thanks @Lu55, I added your comment to the original post.

Comment: @cederlof it looks like your sdk link is broken here is a new one
http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html

Comment: Yep This worked for me in setting up my Jenkins server. Before I added the files to the said location, my build console output read "The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found." Once I added them, the message disappeared (then I removed rebuilt, then re-added and rebuilt to be sure). Now to fix the other 100 errors i am receiving... :p

Comment: Copying files from one machine to another is NEVER the best approach.  Better to find the source and install it.

Comment: As mentioned by @Lu55, you'll get redirected to the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1. The link for Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8, which is actually for .NET Framework 4.5, is: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk.

Comment: Best and easiest solution. I was pulling my hair for a day.

Answer (score 27):

If you're looking for proof it's in the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) here's the installer :

[image]

Note: This still doesn't give you `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` for which you still need to either copy it manually, or install VS on your server.

I just went ahead with the free [Visual Studio Express 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs) which fixed this.

Comment: there's a nuget replacement package for Microsoft.WebApplication.targets -MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets

Comment: Windows 10 link (unverified if it has ref assemblies) https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Answer (score 8):

try to install the Windows SDK for Windows 8, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx, it worked for me.

Comment: FYI - There is an option during the setup to be selective as to what you want to install. Specifically, there is an option for .NET Framework 4.5 / 4.5.1 SDK too.

Comment: This solution worked for me, in my case it's not a build server, but a development machine with Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

This is the official solution which worked for me (TFS 2012)
http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.nl/2012/11/microsoftcommomtargets-warning-983.html

In short:

1. Install SDK or Targetting-Pack for .NET Framework 4.5. But they are
   considerably large in size.
2. The other option is to copy following
   folder from your development machine to your TFS build machine.
   *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5*

Answer (score 2):

**My OS is Win7 x64**

I have the same problem and based on another answer I found a solution:

I have only "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2**"  in my system and to resolve it I renamed v4.52 to v4.5 and it worked.

So for the long run I've made a junction to the 4.5.2 folder and renamed the junction point v.4.5 and it work.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error below on **Windows Server 2016**

> The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework, Version=4.6.1" were not found

I went on my build server "*C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework*" and noticed that I didn't have the required versions.

I then Installed the latest .NET Framework version from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this problem in my project using Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5. Seems like a problem because I moved the project to another directory.

You can fix this issue by verifying that the `HintPath` in the project file is correct or not (.csproj file).

```
<HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll</HintPath>
```

Since I created a new directory and moved my project into that directory, I found that the relative path to the `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` in the `HintPath` was no longer correct, and thus, could not find the library.

Fixing this path resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks has download links for each version of .NET Core and Framework

Comment: .NET 4.5 targeting pack is missing on this page :-(