# Targeting pack for .NET 4.5.2 not installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

When opening an already existing solution in Visual Studio, it says

> The C# project "..." is targeting ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2", which is not installed on this machine.

[image: Screenshot error message]

I have already tried

- Selecting option 2, but it brings me to a generic Microsoft search page (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx)
- Installing the .NET Framework 4.5 SDK (as proposed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21949869/480982))
  [image]

Comment: Despite having the framework already presentmI had similar issue for .net 4.5 based project in VS 2022 .So I followed the accepted answer from this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022194/open-net-framework-4-5-project-in-vs-2022-is-there-any-workaround

But on another machine the same solution didn't help so i just switched back to VS 2021. It worked perfectly alright. 

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Official list of all targeting packs: https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting. Make sure you download the "developer pack", not "runtime".

Direct links to offline installers: [4.5.2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net452-developer-pack), [4.6](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net46-developer-pack), [4.6.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net461-developer-pack), [4.6.2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net462-developer-pack), [4.7](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net47-developer-pack), [4.7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net471-developer-pack), [4.7.2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net472-developer-pack)

This problem seems to affect Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015. The targeting packs are included in Visual Studio 2017.

Outdated links:

- http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx

### How I found that link

First, choose option 1, "Change the target to .NET Framework 4.5"

Next, go to the project options of the affected project, select "Application" and then choose "Install other frameworks..." from the list of target frameworks:

[image: Screenshot Change target framework]

This brings you to a website where you can choose your version of Visual Studio and download the targeting pack (called developer pack).

[image: Website screenshot]

Comment: +1, this is helpful, thanks. However, the link to the web page is all that's needed. Not so much changing the framework (annoying if you have multiple projects in a solution)

Comment: @Assimilater: link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Thomas: link-only answers are discouraged when the link contains actual information you can include in the answer, but in this case the link contains download links, and steps mentioned in your answer are unnecessary, so I would at least put the link at the top of this answer to make it more helpful. That being said, it seems that the link is not working anymore, and that the correct download link is now http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant for VS2017? I'm running into this problem but Microsoft says this should be bundled with VS2017. The installer confirms that the developer pack is installed.

Comment: @tyteen4a03: the linked webseite also says that it should be installed already. Can you uninstall and reinstall it via the Control Panel? Are you sure it is 4.5.2 and not 4.7.2?

Comment: I tried installing the .NET Framework 4.5.2.  VS 2019 still says the .NET 4.5.2 framework is not installed

Comment: LIFE SAVERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue.  When I loaded the project it always asked for the .NET framework 4.5.2 and I was not able to install it because it always said that it was already there.

What worked for me was to install the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637

Give it a try.  It may work for you as well.

Comment: I mistakenly tried installing the "Runtime" and that was already installed. I had to specifically install the "Developer Pack." This all makes sense in retrospect but I was definitely confused before I read this answer.

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue with .NET 4.6.2 (VS2017) - I downloaded the Developer pack from the link provided by the error message and installed, but it didn't help.

But then I opened up the Programs and Features in Windows Control Panel, and selected to "Change" Visual Studio 2017. The installer contains a tab entitled "Individual Components", and in there I saw that Targeting Pack for 4.6.2 was not selected.

Selecting them and selecting "Modify" fixed the problem.

Comment: Same symptoms with .NET 4.7, same fix: opening up Programs and Features and the "Individual Tabs" and select the versions of .NET that you need.

Comment: This also worked with VS 2019 and targeting 4.8.1, though in the VS Installer application the component is listed as "4.8", not "4.8.1"

Answer (score 9):

You need to download the .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack
That link compile all the frameworks in one place

http://scottge.net/2015/07/04/a-complete-list-of-microsoft-sdks-for-download/

Comment: Thank you!  When trying to download 4.5.2 Framework it kept telling me it already installed it, but I WAS able to install the Developer Pack and after doing so I was able to pick 4.5.2 as the target framework!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. In spite of installing developer pack, problem did not seem to go away. I did a VS 2015 repair and voila it started working.

Answer (score 1):

For what it’s worth, after I installed the required Developer Pack, I had to restart Visual Studio before it was detected.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem but downloading the NETFramework Targeting Pack didn't resolve the issue.  I was prompted to change the version or download the correct version.     Neither option worked.  I could see .NET Framework in the registry, on the Visual STudio installer and on the turn programs on and off and verified they were there.     Turns out Visual Studio 2017 Community and 2019 Community installed on c:Program Files.  So it looks here for the framework files.   C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Framework.NETFramework\v?????    For whatever reason the .NETFramework files all loaded here C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Framework.NETFramework\v?????                 Once I copied one of the folders from x86 to the other, it worked and it was recognized and no more error.  I searched but the best solution I found was to create a symbolic link from the one folder to the other.  I didn't feel making a copy was a good long term solution.  So I used mklink and linked the x86 folder to the other.  Now it's working perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

.NET framework is not the same as Targeting Pack. The later needs to be installed in order for Visual Studio to work properly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.