# .NET Framework version 4.6.1 does not appear in VS 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I need to be able to target .Net framework version 4.6.1 for one of my projects. VS 2015 already ships with 4.6.1 as per [Target .Net Platforms](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html) page.

But it isn't listed in the set of available platforms here:

[image]

I downloaded the 4.6.1 framework installer and tried installing. In the process it shows to repair or remove (not install) the framework version, which gives a sign that it is already installed. I moved ahead with repair. Restarted my computer. But even then the same problem exists.

I'm using VS 2015 on a Windows 7 64-bit system. Where am I going wrong? What is wrong here?

Comment: Please check if it (.Net 4.6.1 in programs) is already installed. If so then restart your PC and then start VS. Hopefully you will get it.

Comment: @LexLi as I said I already chose to download other frameworks. I downloaded and installed (rather repaired) the framework. The problem still persists.

Comment: @LexLi Ignorant replies are subject to image risks. Please read the question properly before providing your valuable opinion.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I have installed 4.6.1 by myself. I restarted my PC and started visual studio after that. It didn't work.

Comment: I checked with ASoft .Net version detector. It shows 4.6.1 is installed.

Comment: @BharatGupta It is a problem, which I have never faced. Could it an issue of framework detection by VS2015? You can better ask MS about it. We are all guessing here. (Atleast I am)

Comment: @LexLi, somebody got angry with the criticism and downvoted it :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Targeting pack for .NET 4.5.2 not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931925/targeting-pack-for-net-4-5-2-not-installed)

Comment: I understood the problem. I needed to install 4.6.1 **Dev Pack**. Its resolved. Thanks @LexLi

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem you mentioned - then I installed the .net 4.6.1 developer pack which can be found in this link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978 - And the .net 4.6.1 framework became available to me as a valid target in Visual Studio - hope this helps!

Comment: you are right. But the problem has already been solved. Please checkout the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had this issue I was trying to make a Class library and it didn't give me the choice for a 4.6.1 framework. Turns out I was making a c# Class library for standard or core framework and it only offered limited versions of frameworks I needed a c# Class Library(.Net Framework).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30812935)