# project target framework not installed framework 4.6

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

The visual studio give me error "project target framework no installed on this machine" but i'm installed it and installed developer back framework 4.6 in visual studio 2013 what's the problem ?
i want to use 4.6 framework in my visual studio ?

Comment: you can check the same problem here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931925/targeting-pack-for-net-4-5-2-not-installed
please try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spite of installing developer pack , you should try to do a VS 2013  repair.

Or maybe you are missing some frameworks you should check on Microsoft Site if you have all the requirements .