# Is it possible to use Visual Studio Code with C# plugin in Windows without administrative privileges?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have a C# solution (plain ol' `sln` files) with several `csproj` projects. I just want to setup a powerful code editor that can support for example "go to declaration" navigation on computers with the following restrictions:

1. I don't have administrative rights to and
2. they don't have .NET framework SDK installed or .NET CLI

So for starters I've downloaded the portable version, I've added the C# plugin, I've added the dependencies manually after following [this excellent post](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1028) of Dustin Campbell and now I have the following problems every time I open the project folder:

1. I get the message `The .NET CLI tools cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure .NET CLI tools are installed and are on the path.` I'm fine with that since I'm not interested in debugging and running; just mentioning for the sake of completeness.
2. I get a warning that `Some projects have trouble loading` and I see in the output this message:

> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo
>
> The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

So the first thing I tried was to hack my way around this and see if I could make it work just by dropping the correct reference assemblies into `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468523). But then Bazinga! I don't have administrative rights to do that.

So my question is, can somebody use VS code as a powerful code editor without administrator rights, or I'm just chasing windmills?