# How can I work with .NET framework 4.5 without the developer pack?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I work on a team and one of the older versions of our tool uses .NET framework 4.5 .
Because I'm new to the team I didn't have a 4.5 developer pack installed on my computer and now it's already EoL so it doesn't have a developer pack installation available.
How can I work on the tool if I don't have framework 4.5?

Comment: Are you not using Visual Studio?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am using visual studio

Comment: I thought VS 2022 provided the option for NetFx 4.5 but apparently not. That said, I am able to select NetFx 4.5 as a target for an existing project. Maybe that's because I already had it installed. VS 2019 provides it as an option, but it might be a bit much installing that just for this one thing. Maybe try the recommendation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220615/where-can-i-download-the-net-4-5-multitargeting-pack-for-my-build-server).

Comment: @jmcilhinney It worked! I downloaded the windows 8 SDK and it fixed it. thanks!