# Treat all warnings as errors

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild, warnings

This should be obvious to do, but I just couldn't make it work...

What I'm trying to do is simple: **I would like my compilation to fail with an error if there is a warning**. Yes, the famous `TreatWarningsAsErrors`...

I configured it in my C# project properties

[image: treat warnings as errors]

This results in the expected `TreatWarningsAsErrors` section in my csproj:

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

So far so good, if I add an useless `private` variable in my code, it results in a compilation error:

```
private int unused;
```

> Error 3   Warning as Error: The field 'XXXX.unused' is never used

But the whole problem is, I can't make it work for **assembly reference issues**. If I have a reference to an unknown assembly, the compiler (either devenv or msbuild) throws a warning, but I want an error instead.

Ultimately, I'm trying to configure a gated check-in TFS build configuration, so TFS would reject a commit in case there is a "*The referenced component 'XXXX' could not be found.*" warning. Something simpler than modifying the build process template would be great.

Comment: sort of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495278/how-can-i-treat-msb3245-warning-as-an-error/17515854#17515854

Comment: Try a post build step that inspects the warning

Answer (score 25, accepted):

MSBuild warnings (all start with MSB*) as opposed to CSC warnings cannot be suppressed nor promoted to errors. For the reason the [`ResolveAssemblyReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad3f294.aspx) task prints its messages on the fly and does not aggregate any of them.

The only feasible solution is reading the MSBuild log files created during the TFS build.
I think the most elegant solution is to implement a custom Build [`CodeActivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.codeactivity). The following is a simple activity that will output to results any files containing a given `SearchString`:

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;

namespace MyBuildActivities.FileSystem
{
    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
    public sealed class ReadStringFromFile : CodeActivity
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<IEnumerable<string>> Files { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> SearchString { get; set; }

        public OutArgument<string> Result { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            var files = context.GetValue(Files);
            var searchString = context.GetValue(SearchString);

            var list =
                (files.Where(file => File.ReadAllText(file).Contains(searchString))
                    .Select(file => string.Format("{0} was found at {1}", searchString, file))).ToList();

            if(list.Count > 0)
                Result.Set(context, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));
        }
    }
}
```

Declared in the build process template like so:

```
xmlns:cfs="clr-namespace:MyBuildActivities.FileSystem;assembly=MyBuildActivities"
```

Invoked just at the end of the `Compile and Test for Configuration` sequence:

```
<Sequence DisplayName="Handle MSBuild Errors">
         <Sequence.Variables>
                 <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:IEnumerable(x:String)" Name="logFiles" />                                                                                                                 
                 <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="readStringFromFileResult" />
         </Sequence.Variables>
         <mtbwa:FindMatchingFiles DisplayName="Find Log Files" MatchPattern="[String.Format(&quot;{0}\**\*.log&quot;, logFileDropLocation)]" Result="[logFiles]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
         <cfs:ReadStringFromFile Files="[logFiles]" SearchString="MSB3245" Result="[readStringFromFileResult]" />
         <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage DisplayName="Write Result" Message="[readStringFromFileResult]" Importance="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.High]" />
         <If Condition="[readStringFromFileResult.Count > 0]" DisplayName="If SearchString Was Found" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                 <If.Then>
                          <Throw DisplayName="Throw Exception" Exception="[New Exception(readStringFromFileResult)]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                 </If.Then>
         </If>                                                                                                              
</Sequence>
```

I've tested this on TFS 2012 though it should work for TFS 2010 as well.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... I understand warnings from MSBuild itself cannot be promoted to errors. What I don't understand is why an *unknown assembly reference* is not a CSC warning. Anyway, a custom activity is indeed the way to go, even if at first glance it sounds a bit like overkill for the (apparently) simple use case I had. +1, thanks for your answer.

Comment: To make the solution posted by KMoraz work I had to do the following: 1. Add empty string to Result in the CodeActivity if the string was not found in the files. 2. Change readStringFromFileResult.Count to readStringFromFileResult.Length in the build template. Otherwise I would get a null exception when the string was not found.

Answer (score 26):

MSBuild 15 now supports a `/warnaserror` flag, which forces *MSBuild* warnings to be treated as errors.

MSBuild 15 is intalled with Visual Studio 2017 but can also be [downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/releases)

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/68) explains why it cannot be set via an MSBuild property (tl;dr a property is too late)