# Not getting error on changing the coding validation rule in stylecop.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

I made followinh changes to the stylecop.json file

```
"orderingRules": {"usingDirectivesPlacement": "insideNamespace"}
```

But i am only getting warning and not error in the cs files.

When i place the using directive outside the namespace i don't get any error.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24804486/43846

Comment: It's hard to get the answer you want from the information you've provided. You can learn from some documents with specific steps [How to implement Stylecop warnings](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2015/06/configure-stylecop-with-msbuild-to.html)

Comment: I tried all of this but still, when i place using directive statements outside the namespace i don't get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following steps:

1. Create a new editorconfig File in your project

[image]

[image]

2. Open the editorconfig File, find the perferred 'using' directive placemen in Code Style and adjust it to inside namespace

[image]

3. Save the editorconfig File, and then you will put the using directive in the namespace when you create the class again.

[image]

Finally, you also need to refer to [Should "using" directives be inside or outside a namespace in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-directives-be-inside-or-outside%20-the-namespace-in-c). Because usually stylecop will not check the code outside the namespace

Comment: Is it better to use editorConfig than stylecop.json?

Comment: @ASW As [FAQ for code analysis in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/analyzers-faq?view=vs-2022) said, in the EditorConfig file or text editor When you define code styles on the Visual Studio Options page, you are actually configuring the code analyzer built into Visual Studio. Editor configuration files can be used to enable or disable analyzer rules, and configure NuGet analyzer packages.

Comment: Whereas the StyleCop analyzer is a third-party analyzer installed as a NuGet package to check style consistency in your code. In general, StyleCop rules allow you to set personal preferences for your codebase without recommending one style over another. So there is no good or bad, you should choose a more suitable for your needs

Comment: @wenbingend-MSFt Even if I configure these rules in the editor config, they are not enforced in my build. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: @ASW If you are using EditorConfig to change the location of the using directive? After completing the above steps and saving the settings, it will only work when creating a new class

Comment: @wenbingend-MSFt Isn't there a way to enforce these rules on the existing code?

Comment: @ASW If you want the code format to take effect immediately, here is a very useful [widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55219834/20376806)