# Error on Compiler Code Analysis Warnings - C#

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I work on a distributed team and we have lots of code analysis styles set to Error which keeps the code in pretty good shape style-wise.  However, the one that keeps coming up is CS0169 for unused variables.

I realise that this is not actually a code analysis error and is coming from the compiler.

How can I get it error rather than show a warning?  I tried adding it to the Code Analysis rule set (despite it not being available in the editor!) hoping to trick it!  But no luck ...

Thanks

[image]

Comment: [Treat All Warnings As Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533008/treat-all-warnings-as-errors)?

Comment: That must be really annoying during development. I usually have a lot unused code before I put everything together. Can't you specify a separate rule-set for Debug builds?

Comment: It's surprising actually ... we trialled it on a few whitespace warnings and you quickly train your brain to not do it.  I rarely see any of the errors anymore.