# Msbuild: Detect warnings status for Project with no errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, warnings

We are building lots of projects using msbuild command line. It returns 0 upon (0)Error(s). But it also returns 0 if there are warnings.

At this time we can't set our projects to treat Warnings as Errors as we have 350+ projects.

Is there a way to detect if there were warnings only? Does msbuild can be made to return something special about this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I treat msb3245 warning as an error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495278/how-can-i-treat-msb3245-warning-as-an-error) - not like an *exact* duplicate, but close enough I think: if you want do do some action depeding on warnings, there seems to be no other way then parsing them