# Specify a logger in MSBuild configuration file

Tags: c#, logging, msbuild

I've written some custom logger for my MSBuild process and it's working fine from the command line:

```
msbuild <project> /logger:mylogger.dll
```

the question now is how should I specify my custom logger in the .csproj file so that when I build from Visual Studio my custom logger is used the same way as I use it when running msbuild from the command line.

I haven't found anything to do that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171471.aspx) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx).

Comment: You don't? You do a `<Message Importance="high" Text="FuBar"/>` and you should see that appear in your logging logic.

Comment: My question is how to specify my custom logger in the .csproj file so that when building from Visual Studio, my logger is used.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. In MSBuild API, [RegisterLogger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine.registerlogger.aspx) has to be called before the build is started. You should not change build configuration while the build is already going. You might be able to hack this by creating custom MSBuild task that adds a new logger in the middle of the build, but that would create more problems than it solves, because logger configuration is per build engine, not per project, so when you add/remove loggers, all projects that are involved in the build are affected.

Comment: Well, if it's not possible then saying that "the build is already going" is a poor reason IMHO, since lots of options are configurable (according to the documentation, Properties and PropertyGroups). I think that if you're right it is a missing feature... or even a bug, since I cannot think of any other option available in the msbuild command line that is not available in the configuration files.

Comment: @Luis, I think that is not a bug or missing feature. I think that would be quite inconsistent and cause lots of confusion if some project would decide to use its own logger. Imaging you have this "feature" implemented in MSBuild and you are building a product which contains 100 projects -- you start building your top-level project, and the remaining 99 will be invoked through MSBuild project references. What would happen is by the time build discovers your special project that wants special logger settings, most of the build might be completed. Loggers are specified upfront for a reason.

Comment: Okay, so I'll give the whole picture to you: I want to get the number of warnings detected by a build. That simple thing is not possible in VS. I need to implement a Logger (no idea why but it seems to be the ONLY way) and if doing it I cannot use it from VS. All this drives me to believe that VS sucks.