# Does the new msbuild 15 /warnaserror switch allow to fail on all the warnings except some?

Tags: msbuild

Specifically, I have a problem with MSB3026 - **Could not copy bla-bla-bla to bla-bla-bla. Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file bla-bla-bla because it is being used by another process.**

I know why it happens - two different libraries use two different versions of the same dependency, but I cannot fix that right now.

So, I want to tell MSBuild to treat all the warnings, except MSB3026, as errors.

I do not understand if this is possible. Is it?

Comment: According to the documentation for warnaserror you can pass it a list of warnings, is that what you are looking for? Else there's e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495278/how-can-i-treat-msb3245-could-not-resolve-reference-warning-as-an-error

Comment: Nope, I want all the warnings to be treated as errors, except MSB3026. But I think I have the answer here - https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3062#issuecomment-439945441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided here - https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3062#issuecomment-439945441 by Rainer Sigwald.

There is the flag `/warnasmessage` which demotes warnings to simple messages. It has higher priority than `/warnaserror`, so it is good enough.

To fail on all the warnings, except MSB3026 one would pass this to msbuild `/err /nowarn:MSB3026`

Comment: Did you use warnAsMessage in the end? `/nowarn:MSB3026` (or specifically, `/p:NoWarn=AD0001%2CMSB3026`) doesn't seem to fix this.

Comment: Yes. It works. What is `AD0001%2CMSB3026` ?  I assume you wish to suppress both AD0001 and MSB3026.  `/p:NoWarn` is **not** the same as `/nowarn`. So, try `/nowarn`

Comment: Yes, that would be a suppress for two error codes. Ah I see, that's very valuable, thank you!